# How can I create a new categorical variable and keep NAs as it is?

Tags: r

```
EC <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), past_smoking=c("1","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0"),current_smoking=c("0","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","0"))

EC

  id past_smoking current_smoking
1  1            1               0
2  2            0               1
3  3            0               1
4  4           NA               1
5  5            1               0
6  6            0               1
7  7            0               1
8  8            NA               NA
9  9            0               0
```

my question is: how can I create a new categorical variable with no_smoking =0, current_smoking=1 and past_smoking =2 and keep  NAs as it is? Because with the previous solution all the NAs become fake values "1" or "0"

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
transform(
  EC,
  category = current_smoking + 2*past_smoking
)
```

which gives

```
  id past_smoking current_smoking category
1  1            1               0        2
2  2            0               1        1
3  3            0               1        1
4  4           NA               1       NA
5  5            1               0        2
6  6            0               1        1
7  7            0               1        1
8  8           NA              NA       NA
9  9            0               0        0
```

**Data**

```
> dput(EC)
structure(list(id = 1:9, past_smoking = c(1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L,
0L, 0L, NA, 0L), current_smoking = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L,
1L, NA, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3",
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EC %>% 
  mutate(
    no_smoking = case_when(
      is.na(past_smoking) | is.na(current_smoking) ~ NA_character_,
      past_smoking =='1' ~ '2',
      current_smoking == '1' ~ '1', 
      TRUE ~ '0'
    )
  )
```

Comment: Any explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `within`.

```
dat <- within(dat, {
  new_cat <- NA  ## initialize new cat
  new_cat[past_smoking == 0 & current_smoking == 0] <- 0
  new_cat[current_smoking == 1] <- 1
  new_cat[past_smoking == 1] <- 2
})
dat
#   id past_smoking current_smoking new_cat
# 1  1            1               0       2
# 2  2            0               1       1
# 3  3            0               1       1
# 4  4           NA               1       1
# 5  5            1               0       2
# 6  6            0               1       1
# 7  7            0               1       1
# 8  8           NA              NA      NA
# 9  9            0               0       0
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(text="
id past_smoking current_smoking
1  1            1               0
2  2            0               1
3  3            0               1
4  4           NA               1
5  5            1               0
6  6            0               1
7  7            0               1
8  8            NA               NA
9  9            0               0
", header=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr` similar to the same in `base R` `transform`

```
library(dplyr)
EC %>%
    mutate(category = current_smoking + 2 * past_smoking)
```